# CQRS - how to define Entity which are with aggregation relationship?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Say I have some `Brand`s, each `Brand` have some `Product`s. When define Entity follow CQRS pattern, is it good practice having `List<Product>` as a field of `Brand`? Or one Entity should never hold another Entity, I need to define another Entity `BrandProductRelationship`?

```
public class Brand {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Product> products;
}

public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

If so, when define brand created event, looks like I need to pass `List<Product>` as a parameter, which seems complicate.

```
public class BrandCreated implements Event {
    public Brand apply() {
        return new Brand(id, name, products);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities that contain other entities is fine, provided that they are all part of the same consistency boundary.

The story is different with *aggregates*; you don't normally want to have two different paths to modify the state of a single specific entity, so having one aggregate contain another is discouraged.  In this case, you'll normally have one aggregate contain an *identifier* that can be used to look up the other.

```
public class Brand {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> productsIds;
}
```

Is better; but it demonstrates [primitive obsession](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrimitiveObsession).  In Domain Driven Design, entities are more likely to be expressed using values from the domain model itself.

```
public class Brand {
    private Identifier<Brand> id;
    private Name name;
    private List<ProductId> productsIds;
}
```

or even

```
public class Brand {
    private Identifier<Brand> id;
    private Name name;
    private ProductCatalog catalog;
}
```

Comment: So change `private List<Product> products;` to something like `private List<String> productIds;`?